# Sorting list of cons by second object

Tags: sorting, lisp

I need to sort list of cons elements by cdr element.
For example:

```
(aaa.4 bbb.2 ccc.6 ddd.9 eee.3) => (bbb.2 eee.3 aaa.4 ccc.6 ddd.9)
```

Help me please, i just start learning Lisp.

Comment: `(sort list :key #'cdr)`.  Note that `sort` is permitted to scramble the list in place; if the original list may not be destroyed use `(sort (copy-list list) :key #'cdr)`.

Comment: this is a great beginner book and a free download: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 1):

This `(aaa.4 bbb.2 ccc.6 ddd.9 eee.3)` is not a list of conses, but a list of symbols named `"aaa.4"`, `"bbb.2"` etc.

What your text implies is rather something like this:

```
((aaa . 4)
 (bbb . 2)
 (ccc . 6)
 (ddd . 9)
 (eee . 3))
```

You can sort a list by some key with the `key` argument to `sort`:

```
(sort list #'< :key #'cdr)
```

`Sort` may destructively modify the input list in order to create the sorted output list.  To protect against that, copy it first:

```
(sort (copy-list list) #'< :key #'cdr)
```